# sed extract substring between two characters from a file and save to variable

Tags: bash, sed, substring

I am automatically building a package. The automated script needs to get the version of the package to build.
I need to get the string of the python script main.py. It says in line 15

```
VERSION="0.2.0.4" #DO NOT MOVE THIS LINE
```

I need the 0.2.0.4, in future it can easily become 0.10.3.15 or so, so the sed command must not have a fixed length.
I found this on stackoverflow:

```
sed -n '15s/.*\#\([0-9]*\)\/.*/\1/p'
```

"This suppresses everything but the second line, then echos the digits between # and /"

This does not work (adjusted). Which is the last "/"? How can I save the output into a variable called "version"?

```
version = sed -n ...
```

throws an error

> command -n not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F= 'NR==15 {gsub("\"","",$2); print $2}' main.py
0.2.0.4
```

#### Explanation

- `NR==15` performs actions on line number 15.
- `-F=` defines the field separator as `=`.
- `{gsub("\"","",$2); print $2}` removes the `"` character on the 2nd field and prints it.

#### Update

> to be more specific the line is version="0.2.0.4" #DO NOT MOVE THIS
>   LINE

```
$ awk -F[=#] 'NR==15 {gsub("\"","",$2); print $2}' main.py
0.2.0.4
```

Using multiple field separator `-F[=#]` which means it can be either `#` or `=`.

To save it into your `version` variable, use the expression `var=$(command)` like:

```
version=$(awk -F[=#] 'NR==15 {gsub("\"","",$2); print $2}' main.py)
```

Comment: That's halfway working, it does not stop after the `4` and prints the rest of the line. to be more specific the line is `version="0.2.0.4" #DO NOT MOVE THIS LINE`

Comment: @user2366975 it is working as you gave the input. Please update your question indicating the real input so that the result can work.

Comment: I see your point but i thought it was clear from the question "between two characters"

Comment: Sorry I did not remember that part, @user2366975 :D

Comment: This seems to work much better, still I have 2 notation questions: Is the output a string or what? I need to create a file that has the version in it. And how can I check the output "version" without only calling "awk"?

Comment: Yes, the output is a string. You can call it with `echo "the result is $version"`. You can also create a file like `echo "test info" >> myfile.$version", which will create `myfile.0.2.0.4`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need version number.

```
awk -F\" 'NR==15 {print $2}' main.py
```

This prints everything between `"` on line 15.  Like `0.2.0.4`

Comment: This is also a very good answer, I combined it with the accepted one. Sorry that I can only accept one, but voted up... The author of the accepted answer put so much effort in it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed -n '15s/[^"]*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p' inputfile
```

In order to assign it to a variable, say:

```
VARIABLE=$(sed -n '15s/[^"]*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p' inputfile)
```

In order to remove the dependency that the `VERSION` would occur only on line 15, you could say:

```
sed -n '/^VERSION=/ s/[^"]*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

there should not be space in assigning variables

```
version=$(your code)

version=$(sed -r -i '15s/.*\"\([0-9]*\)\/.*/"/p' main.py)
```

OR

```
version=`sed -r -i '15s/.*\"\([0-9]*\)\/.*/"/p' main.py`
```

Comment: `version=sed -r -i '15s/.*\"\([0-9]*\)\/.*/"/p' main.py`

Comment: and how can I see the output? I even don't know if it does anything.

Comment: echo $version should give you the output